# Can we use @RequestParam along with @RequestBody in Spring Controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

```
public ResponseEntity<String> action(@RequestParam(value = "id") final String id,@RequestBody item item)
throws IllegalAccessException {
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I get Bad request error whenever I hit this URL.

Request JSON:

```
{
    "id": "rw121232323e",
    "item":{
            "code": "shirt",
            "qty":10
           }
}
```

But the code works when I have only `@RequestBody` in my controller method.
Wanted to know if `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody` can be used together.

Comment: "RequestBody" is used typically for POST and PUT API verbs. This mentioned as part of the annotation @RequestMapping. Like Example :   @RequestMapping(value = "/mapping", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = "application/json")

Answer (score 1):

With the example json you provided, the id is part of the body, not a request parameter. Also, the default value for the "required" attribute of `@RequestParam` is true, and this I suspect is the reason you are getting the Bad Request response. Either you specify the parameter in the url (by putting `?id=yourId` at the end of it), or you specify the request parameter like this :

```
@RequestParam(required = false) String id
```